# How do I determine what is the issue with a 500 error on a HttpClient.PostAsJsonAsync call?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I am making a call to a Web API that I wrote. I am working through the bugs on both sides and am getting a 500 error. I want to see that is in that error message to see what might be the problem. How do I find that?

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    var fooURL = Url.RouteUrl("PayrollApi", new { httproute = string.Empty, controller = "LeaveRequest" }, Request.Url.Scheme);
    var repsonse = client.PostAsJsonAsync(fooURL, leaveRequest).Result;
}
```

I don't see where that text might be stored so I can figure out what other bugs need to be fixed. How do I get that text?

**Update**: something I didn't clarify. I put a breakpoint on the WebAPI I am calling and the break point is never hit. *However*, when I call it from Poster, I hit the break point. The URL is correct.

```
public HttpResponseMessage Post([FromBody]LeaveRequest value)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        // code here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am making a call to a Web API that I wrote.  I want to see that is
>   in that error message to see what might be the problem.

You might want to put the code you have in `PayrollApi.LeaveRequest` in a try-catch block, something like:

```
public HttpResponseMessage LeaveRequest()
{
    try {
        // do something here
    } 
    catch(Exception ex) {
        // this try-catch block can be temporary 
        // just to catch that 500-error (or any unexpected error)
        // you would not normally have this code-block
        var badResponse = request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        badResponse.ReasonPhrase = "include ex.StackTrace here just for debugging";
    }
}
```

Then make a call inside a try-catch block to capture that extra error:

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    // rest of your code goes here
    try
    {
        var repsonse = client.PostAsJsonAsync(fooURL, leaveRequest).Result;
    }
    catch(HttpRequestException httpEx)
    {
         // determine error here by inspecting httpEx.Message         
    }
}
```

`httpEx.Message` can have this message:

> Response status code does not indicate success: 500
>   ({stack_trace_goes_here}).

Answer (score 22):

I was able to make a change to get the error message:

```
var repsonse = client.PostAsJsonAsync(fooURL, leaveRequest).Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

instead of

```
var repsonse = client.PostAsJsonAsync(fooURL, leaveRequest).Result;
```

I was then able to see my error and fix it.